# Android AppCompat Actionbar customization

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

Im a little torn on appcompat at the moment. While it seems to be praised as an all in one answer, documentation seems really weak and im kind of lost on how to do a lot of things on it. What im ultimately trying to do is remove the Title on the actionbar, add buttons with custom icons (I have managed this one) and add a sliding side bar. I have been away from Android for a while now. I had started by opening up Android Studio and going with the Actionbar with Sidebar template. Seemed like the correct thing to do. As soon as I open up the activity class, I see that ActionBarActiivty has been deprecated. Ok, so I switch that out with AppCompatActivity.... Well now it wont run, get a stack trace saying it cannot be cast. On top of that it seems you cannot access the actionbar through code anymore either. YOu used to simply be able to grab the actionbar and call hide(). Here is some snippets for what I have tried

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
        parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:displayOptions"></item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Tried that to remove the title from the actionbar as suggested on another question. Is there a api reference page that has a list of all the item names that you can call and what they do?

Comment: Have you tried working with Toolbar? It is easy to customize.  Also you need to call getSupportActionBar(). You can also add items within the Toolbar through xml which is nice. And by sidebar, do you mean Navigation drawer?

Comment: Problem with the toolbar is its restricted to Android 5.0. I would love to use it (though I think im about to quit programming android altogether after this morning), but I need backwards compatibility. I tend to try to stay away from new apis for a while until it has better support

Comment: The toolbar is backwards compatible to v7 and up. It should run on any device that is being used today. The toolbar is pretty solid and I have not seen any flaws with its current updates.

Comment: Ah ok, ill have to look into that. Been a rough morning trying to get back into this. First Intel HAXM broke my internet completely to the point where I had to system restore, to the actionbar mess, and now the AVD wont start and I cant get adb to recognize my phone.

Comment: Damn. If you need a hand setting it up I can send you my email and get you moving.  Let me know and I will post it.

Comment: I appreciate it. Ill let you know if I cant get it worked out. Guess its my own fault for stopping for a year. Things changed a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81132/discussion-between-eugene-h-and-shaun).

Answer (score 0):

So the reason you can't access the actionbar anymore is because you are not using it. These helped me out a lot when it came to learning appcompatactivity.

http://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-toolbar-goodbye-action-bar/

http://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-appcompatactivity-goodbye-actionbaractivity/

Also to remove the title, it's as simple as calling setTitle(null) in onCreate.

Comment: Problem is this is using Xamarin and im using Android Studio. Would love to use Xamarin, but its pricing keeps me away

Comment: I don't use Xamarin, I use android studio as well. The general concept of how to implement the code into your project is roughly the same in both cases.